# Azure Site Recovery - VMware to Azure - a few issues

Tags: azure, powershell, vmware

I have ASR set up from Vmware to Azure.
I downloaded the ASR appliance from Azure, installed it in Vmware, registered and replicated a couple of VMs. I have done a test failover and a full failover and failback. All worked. I have done much of this with powershell.

Now Im trying to automate enabling replication with powershell and some things are not working.

I can get the fabric and the container

```
$asrFabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric
$asrContainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $asrFabric
```

But I cannot get info on the vcenter, this command returns blank.

```
Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrvCenter -Fabric $asrFabric
```

In the portal, under the vault and Site Recovery, Enable Replication, I can see my vCenter Server, and all the virtual machines from Vmware. This is how I set up the replication I already have going. So don't know why `Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrvCenter` returns nothing.

I can get the vmware siteID.

```
$VmwareSiteID = $asrFabric.FabricSpecificDetails.VmwareSiteId
```

And I can get all protectable items.

```
$allProtectableItems = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectableItem -ProtectionContainer $asrContainer -SiteId $VmwareSiteID
```

I get 631 items.

Following the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-disaster-recovery-powershell .. I was trying to enable replication for a VM.

`New-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem` requires the -Account parameter. This is account credentials that I supplied at registration. The article says that the accounts can be found this way:

```
$AccountHandles = $asrabric.FabricSpecificDetails.RunAsAccounts
```

but my fabric has no item called .RunAsAccounts.

My `$asrFabric.FabricSpecificDetails` looks like this

```
VmwareSiteId       : /subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/zz/providers/Microsoft.OffAzure/VMwareSites/yyy
PhysicalSiteId     : /subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/zz/providers/Microsoft.OffAzure/ServerSites/yyy
ServiceEndpoint    : https://pod01-srs1.ukw.hypervrecoverymanager.windowsazure.com
ServiceResourceId  : 111111111111111111
ServiceContainerId : 22222222222222
DataPlaneUri       : https://pod01-prot2.ukw.backup.windowsazure.com
ControlPlaneUri    : https://pod01-rcm1.ukw.hypervrecoverymanager.windowsazure.com
ProcessServers     : {}
RcmProxies         : {}
PushInstallers     : {}
ReplicationAgents  : {}
ReprotectAgents    : {}
MarsAgents         : {}
Dras               : {}
AgentDetails       : {}
```

and as you can see there is no RunAssAccounts and also there is no ProcessServer.
I absolutely have a processServer. When I go to Site Recovery Infrastructure > ASR Replication Appliances, I can see my appliance or processServer.
It shows as LMGMT-ASR01 (10.4.10.27).

If I start to enable replication for a VM in portal, I can see the vcenter, the process server and the RunAs accounts. But I cannot get them with powershell.
Am I doing something wrong, is there another way to get the info I need?

thanks